# Thought experiment on relative motion

Tags: relative-motion, thought-experiment

Imagine two persons (*A* and *B*) in a vacuum in outer space that are in front of each other and are not in motion.
Say that suddenly *A* starts moving away with a constant velocity from *B*.

In this case, would *A* or *B* be able to determine themselves in any way that *A* is the one who is actually moving and *B* is stationary?

I think they can reach only one of the following conclusions but never know who was actually moving:

1. *A* is moving and *B* is stationary.
2. *B* is moving and *A* is stationary.
3. *A* and *B* are both moving with some velocity from each other that could be equal or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If *A* changes their velocity then you can say absolutely that *A* has accelerated, since acceleration is not a relative effect. That said, you still cannot say in any absolute sense who is moving, since all movement is relative. *A* is moving relative to *B* and *B* is moving relative to *A* - both statements hold true at the same time.

Likewise, the concept of 'being stationary' only makes sense if you specify a reference frame relative to which something is motionless.

Comment: _If A changes their velocity then you can say absolutely that A has accelerated, since acceleration is not a relative effect._ Can _A_ or _B_ perceive that _A_ has accelerated in this case?

Comment: That depends on the circumstances. If the A was a person, say, and the acceleration was very gradual, they might not feel it, and they might mistakenly think it was B who had started to move.

Comment: Say that the acceleration was very quick (was of very high magnitude), then also would _A_ be able to perceive that he/she was the one who accelerated, considering that _A_'s body is rigid, i.e., all body parts/organs accelerate simultaneously at the same instant?

Comment: If, hypothetically, you could introduce a force that acted upon all parts of A's body equally (as gravity does) without it acting on B, then yes A might have the impression that it is B that has accelerated.

Answer (score 2):

I have the first of your statements.

*Imagine two persons (A and B) in a vacuum in outer space that are in front of each other and are not in motion* **relative to one another**.

*Say that suddenly A starts moving away with a constant velocity from B.*

Introducing an acceleration changes things.

(1) A pushes B hence B pushes A ( Newton’s third law).
Velocities relative to their original position (centre of mass) could be found as well as the relative velocity between them.

(2) A throws a ball.
B will not move relative to the original position and the ball and A will be moving relative to each other and relative to B whose position is also the original position of A and the ball.

Answer (score 1):

To come from rest v=0 to v=const you would need a force acting on the body, hence de/acceleration, which you would detect if you allow some kind of instrumentations, unless you do it infinite slowly.

Comment: What do you mean by _de/acceleration_?

Comment: acceleration to a  from v=0 to v and than you must stop the acceleration to 0 (going from a to 0)

Answer (score 1):

> suddenly A starts moving

Things don't just start moving. Something had to give A a shove. (I.e., something applied *force* to A to make them start moving.) That's called "acceleration," and it can be measured. Even though, from A's point of view, it may *look* like B was the one who started moving, It's *A* who feels the shove. B does not feel it.

---

After the acceleration stops...

> I think they can reach only one of the following conclusions...

Not true. Once the acceleration stops, all three of your "conclusions" are equally valid. What you are comparing there are three different [*inertial frames of reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference). One may be more *convenient* than another (e.g., it sometimes makes more sense for me to think of myself as "stationary",) but experiments done and described in any inertial coordinate frame obey all the same laws of physics as experiments done on the same subjects in any other inertial coordinate frame.

Comment: _It's A who feels the shove. B does not feel it._ OK, let's consider that there is a non-contact force that causes the change in state of motion of _A_, so in the meantime the force is acting, would _A_ be able to 'feel/experience' that his/her velocity is changing? I don't think _A_ will be able to perceive that.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. It's the essence of the principle of relativity that there is no experiment that can distinguish between A's and B's constant velocity reference frames.

However, if A was also there when they start accelerating (which they must have experienced, because they were originally at rest) then A will be able to tell that A is the one that moved.

Comment: Can _A_ or _B_ perceive that _A_ has accelerated in this case? I don't think so. Also, what do you mean when you say _However, if A was also there when they start accelerating_?

Comment: @silica19 If A accelerated, they can certainly perceive it, because they would have felt a force on them. You can't accelerate without feeling that force.

Comment: What if there was a non-contact force acting on _A_ and also considering that _A_'s body is rigid, i.e., all body parts/organs accelerate simultaneously at the same instant?

Comment: @silica19 doesn't matter, the body must experience a force or it cannot accelerate.

Comment: I'm asking that in this case would _A_ or _B_ perceive that _A_ accelerated? I don't think so.

Comment: @silica19 A would of course perceive themselves to have accelerated because they feel the force, and B would do the same because they can see A accelerating but feel no force themselves. I don't understand what you mean by "I don't think so".

Comment: But the force is a non-contact force, so in what sense does _A_ feel the force? I meant _I don't think so_ that _A_ would understand that he/she is accelerating.

Comment: @silica19 I don't understand what you mean. Why can't you feel a non-contact force? If you for example hold a magnet close to another magnet such that the North poles are facing one another, you'd still feel a force even though the magnetic force is non-contact.

Comment: The example you gave would be of a contact force because as you said "hold a magnet close to another magnet", the magnet in your hand which is in contact is attracted to the other magnet causing your hand to be pulled as you're holding it. An example of a non-contact force can be gravity.

Comment: @silica19 magnetic force is definitely non-contact since the two magnets are not in direct contact. If you are thinking of "hand" then imagine a cyborg where the magnet is grafted into their hand. Physically, this changes nothing.

Comment: Yes, magnetic force is a non-contact force and I've understood what you're trying to stay. But also, in this case, you feel the force because you have the power to resist the movement of the magnet by holding it. You could think of this as a rope pulling your hand, when you try to resist the movement caused by the rope, you feel the force. If you don't resist the force on your hand, then also you can know that there is a force acting as you can literally see your hand moving without your control. The case we are discussing is different.

Comment: @silica19 how is it different? Remember, if there is acceleration, there must be a force, and there is no contact.

Comment: Yes, but what we are discussing is that if a non-contact force causes _A_ to accelerate, would _A_ be able to 'feel/experience' that his/her velocity is changing, considering that _A_'s body is rigid, i.e., all body parts/organs accelerate simultaneously at the same instant? I don't think _A_ will be able to perceive that.